# "Para que" + pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, sintaxis, pretérito

Leyendo un libro me di cuenta de que hay combinaciones *"para que + un verbo en presente de subjuntivo / pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo"* (y muy muy pocos casos con *pretérito perfecto compuesto de subjuntivo*).

Nunca he encontrado oraciones finales con *"para que + pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo"*. ¿Acaso no se usa? ¿Es porqué la acción de la subordinada es considerada como deseada y en consecuencia como hipotética (e incompatible con un tiempo pasado) o hay alguna otra explicación?

Gracias.

Comment: Nos presenta mas ejemplos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El subjuntivo puede muy bien expresar una acción hipotética en el pasado, que viene a ser lo mismo que una hipótesis [contrafáctica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrafactual), y es lo que se hace en combinación con *si* ("Si hubieses hecho esto, no habría ocurrido esto otro"). De manera que no es ésa la razón.

Entiendo que *para que* + subjuntivo expresa un objetivo hipotético. Si el objetivo debía cumplirse en el pasado como efecto de una acción, la acción debe haber sido anterior. La semántica y la sintaxis entonces no permitirían el uso de un tiempo pluscuamperfecto en la cláusula que expresa el efecto, porque el pluscuamperfecto sirve precisamente para expresar anterioridad.

Supongamos que queremos forzar el uso del pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo en frases como éstas:

> *Te di el dinero para que hicieses algo útil con él. Antes de eso te había ofrecido mi ayuda para que no estuvieses solo en esto.*

No importa cómo, es imposible transformar gramaticalmente las proposiciones en subjuntivo en pluscuamperfectas. Si yo dijese *para que hubieses hecho algo útil con él* o *para que no hubieses estado solo*, sugeriría objetivos anteriores a la acción destinada a producirlo. Me imagino que esto sólo tendría utilidad en un relato de ciencia ficción o fantasía sobre viajes en el tiempo.

Answer (score 3):

Sí que se puede usar el pluscuamperfecto. Ejemplo:

> Juan llegó tarde. Habría hecho falta un milagro para que hubiese llegado a tiempo.

En Google Books hay [algunos ejemplos más](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22para%20que%20hubiese%22#tbm=bks&q=%22para%20que%20hubiera%22).

Pero, como puedes observar, es una construcción algo enrevesada, y la verdad es que es mucho más común usar el imperfecto (`para que llegase a tiempo`).